# How to remove %2F generated by url() in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, string, url, laravel-5, encode

I need to get the name of my image and to add img folder before the name of the figure. I use url() function like below

```
{{ url('img', 'articles/mypic.jpg') }}
```

The issue is that I don't get

http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/articles/mypic.jpg

but I get %2F instead of /

http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/articles%2Fmypic.jpg

it works fine in localhost, but does not work properly on my server. I need to reconfigure apache to make it work, and I would like to avoid reconfiguring Apache. Could I avoid encoding / into %2F?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urldecode`, but you needn't to decode it for browser will process it well without decode.

```
php > echo urldecode("http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/articles%2Fmypic.jpg");
http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/articles/mypic.jpg
```

Comment: The issue is that the same browser is processing it well when I run it at localhost, but does not process it when I run it on my server. I get 404 error on the server if %2F is present. It works with this fix, but can I use just url() and avoid %2F?